# Move drag and drop handle to other side

Tags: theming, entities

I want to move the drag and drop handle to the other side of a form, to the same location as the row weight selections.  I am talking about the tabledrag handles, as shown below:

[image]

I am using [Corolla](http://drupal.org/project/corolla) if it makes a difference.

Comment: Added image.  Interesteing question; that element is in a cell in a tablerow.

Comment: It looks to be hard coded into `Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.makeDraggable` (in /misc/tabledrag.js). It uses `td:first` as the selector to add the handle to. There is an `rtl` option under `Drupal.tableDrag` based on the css `direction` of the table - that would probably simulate the effect but I'm not sure how you'd do it without making the table semantically RTL. Either way I think you're looking at overriding a couple of the tabledrag objects/functions

Comment: any idea on where to start? I dont have much experience with overriding anything and have no clue what to do.

Comment: It's a little workaround, but I tried with the Bartik theme, and it seems like you can override it with CSS. This should get you started: `form .field-multiple-table td.field-multiple-drag { position:absolute;right:0; }`. Not sure it works in all browsers though.

Comment: enzipher thanks! one last question, where in bartik did you put this?

Comment: enzipher thanks! one last question, where in bartik did you put this?  - EDIT nvm.
it moves to the far right behind my block.
if i change it to right:520px then it displays after form. I guess now i need to be conscious of any draggable views i have. thank you problem solved.

Comment: two changes i made 
"form .field-multiple-table td.field-multiple-drag {
  width: 30px;
  padding-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px; /*LTR*/
}
form .field-multiple-table td.field-multiple-drag a.tabledrag-handle {
  padding-right: 0em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 520px; /*LTR*/"

Answer (score 0):

two changes i made

```
form .field-multiple-table td.field-multiple-drag { width: 30px; padding-right: 0; position: absolute; left:0px; /*LTR*/ } form .field-multiple-table td.field-multiple-drag a.tabledrag-handle { padding-right: 0em; position: absolute; left: 520px; /*LTR*/
```